# Plesk log - reading HTTP headers

Tags: linux, centos, logging

I'm trawling through Plesk access logs for a troublesome issue and there's one part I'm not clear on.

I've grepped through the log to pull all requests for a particular page, and the vast majority look like this:

```
123.123.123.123 - - [16/Dec/2009:23:47:29 +0000] "POST /mypage.php HTTP/1.0" 200 336 "-" "(useragent string)"
```

However, the requests where there has been an issue, the line looks like this:

```
123.123.123.123 - - [16/Dec/2009:23:47:29 +0000] "POST /mypage.php HTTP/1.0" 200 447 "-" "(useragent string)"
```

The difference being the '447' rather than '336' after the 200 response code. This could be a red herring, but I have no idea what this 3 digit code is - all I know is that it doesn't seem to be part of the HTTP response code!

Can anyone decipher it for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numerical value after the HTTP status code in your log file is the size of the response (only body, no headers) in bytes.

Also read the Apache httpd documentation on [Log Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html).